# Submit initial selection in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, submit, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown list which runs the javascript function `printResult` when the default selection is changed:

```
<form action="">
<select name="list" onChange="printResult();">
    <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected> Option 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I would like the form to submit the option that is selected as default when the page loads, as well as when another option is selected. All tutorials I can find only cover `onchange`, rather than what I want.

Is this possible?

Comment: War so you mean by "submit"? Sending to a server or so?

Comment: What I mean is to pass 'option 2' (which is selected when the page loads) to the javascript function when the page loads. Currently, it does not do this.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  When you post a question it should never be necessary to ask you what you mean. Guessing ... you mean you want the onChange event to fire whenever the page is loaded, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to  call a function on page load do this:

```
<body onload="printResult();">

<form action="">
<select name="list" onChange="printResult();">
    <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected> Option 2</option>
    <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
```

or in jquery you can postpone the load function anywhere in the page :

```
$(window).on("load",function(){ printResult(); })
```

or on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){printResult();})
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.